# How to compile and install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, compiling

How can I compile and install the package [ia32-libs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It's not duplicate. I'm asking about how to compile it in 14.04.

Comment: To compile see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo or any compiling guide. Note: when compiling you generally have to manually resolve dependencies, although there are some commands to help. It will depend on what you are compiling. Update your question if you have a problem somewhere.

Comment: Does the source code have dependency?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: It will not make downloading dependencies automatic. I hope compiling will use new packages instead of a lot of old packages that will be downloaded.