# Can't install oracle java and gcc-4.9:i386 on 64bit OS

Tags: java, gcc, oracle

I have installed oracle jdk7 from the WebUpd8team PPA and it's working just fine, now I want to run a 32bit game (Dwarf fortress with dfhack, for those who know it) and that requires gcc-4.9:i386 which depends on binutils:i386, but jdk7 depends on binutils (the 64bit version) and those two seem to be in conflict, cause when I try to install one it removes the other one. Is there a way to have both jdk7 (64bit) and gcc-4.9:i386 at the same time on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you mean JDK7? That came out quite a while ago. We're late into JDK8.

Second, have you tried installing ia32-libs yet? It has technically been removed from the central repos (Canonical, etc.); but its jobs is to act as a crutch for strictly 32-bit programs that need to run on 64-bit systems. Details here: [How to compile and install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490749/how-to-compile-and-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Hopefully Dwarf Fortress will implement some support for 64-bit architectures eventually, though. I remember having a similar problem with Steam's buggy support for 64-bit Flash; thankfully it was eventually fixed.